# Git Deleting a branch called "-delete"

Tags: git, git-branch

I made a mistake.

I ended up accidently creating a branch called "-delete", and now I can't delete it locally.

when I run the command: $ git branch -d -delete I get the following error

error: did you mean --delete (with two dashes)?

I can't seem to delete this branch at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you put the branch name in quotes?

Comment: @BransonSmith Quotes help to hide things from the shell. The problem in the question is with git, not shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most option parsers including Git options can be separated from arguments with `--`:

```
git branch -d -- -delete
```

Branches live in `refs/heads/` namespace so you can delete one by full path:

```
 git update-ref -d refs/heads/-delete
```

Comment: This made progress, but now I get this error "error: branch '-delete' not found." Even though it is listed when i search my current branch list

Comment: @JasonSmithCode Can we see the text output of `git for-each-ref` ?

Comment: @JasonSmithCode See the updated answer: `git update-ref -d refs/heads/-delete`

Comment: 18e8294e1cfaeef35b7e65dff0b33a245996732b commit refs/heads/grid
418efb4bccc700c615b014d1d1ee54e209438c58 commit refs/heads/main
dcd9d61695dbd9099d4c92d1e20bad584e788df2 commit refs/heads/–delete
00384df3169e9a3f446b85830e524a0717d81ecc commit refs/remotes/origin/footer
18e8294e1cfaeef35b7e65dff0b33a245996732b commit refs/remotes/origin/grid
fb99e05f07314c739419b943ce9cc7e56ba13e95 commit refs/remotes/origin/header
c33f97397013b6414f60292e042a39436e3a042b commit refs/remotes/origin/main
dcd9d61695dbd9099d4c92d1e20bad584e788df2 commit refs/remotes/origin/stripReactApp

Comment: After performing the command git update-ref -d refs/heads/-delete the -delete branch is still there  :D

Comment: Because it's not `-delete`, it's `–delete`. M-dash or N-dash, not just minus. Copy/paste the branch name into the command including the special character. `git branch -d –delete` should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a graphical repository browser like gitk.

In gitk, right-click on the green branch label and select "delete".